# Не реагирует обработчик событий на кнопке

Tags: asp.net

Программно добавляю кнопку

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        form1.Controls.Add(tt);
    }

    protected void create_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int k = -1;
        int l = -1;
        if ((int.TryParse(row.Text, out k)) && (int.TryParse(cell.Text, out l)))
        {
            if ((k > 0) && (l > 0))
            {
                HtmlTable table = new HtmlTable();
                table.Border = 1;
                table.CellPadding = 3;
                table.CellSpacing = 3;
                table.BorderColor = "red";
                HtmlTableRow new_row;
                HtmlTableCell new_cell;
                for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
                {
                    new_row = new HtmlTableRow();
                    new_row.BgColor = (i % 2 == 0 ? "lightyellow" : "lightcyan");
                    for (int j = 1; j <= l; j++)
                    {
                        new_cell = new HtmlTableCell();
                        if (i == k)
                        {
                            Button btn = new Button();
                            btn.ID = "" + j + i;
                            btn.Click += new EventHandler(this.btn_Click);
                            btn.Text = "Автор";
                            new_cell.Controls.Add(btn);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            new_cell.InnerHtml = "" + i + j;
                        }
                        new_row.Cells.Add(new_cell);
                    }
                    table.Rows.Add(new_row);
                }
                form1.Controls.Add(table);
            }
        }
    }


<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <p>
        <a>Введіть кількість рядків</a>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="row"></asp:TextBox>
        <a>&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp Введіть кількість стовпців</a>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="cell"></asp:TextBox>
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:Button ID="create" runat="server" Text="Побудувати таблицю" OnClick="create_Click"/>             
    </p>
</div>
</form>
```

Но не срабатывает обработчик события.

Comment: нужно больше кода - где создаете, как проверяете и т.д.

Comment: @Grundy добавил код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Динамические компоненты в ASP.NET надо создавать на каждую загрузку страницы, после того как они были созданы в первый раз. На каждый запрос создается новый объект класса Вашей страницы, который не знает/не помнит, что с ним происходило во время обработки предыдущих запросов (тут есть нюансы). Сохраняйте флаг, показывающий, что кнопка создана (в `Session`, `ViewState`, hidden поле, базе), и проверяйте его не позднее, чем в `Page_Load`.

У Вас, во время `PostBack`а, происходящего из-за нажатия на кнопку "Автор", этой кнопки "Автор" на сервере не существует. Нет объекта, который скажет: "На меня нажали, надо вызвать обработчик события".

Update

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlTable" runat="server"></asp:Panel>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (Session["RowCount"] != null && Session["ColumnCount"] != null)
  {
    int rows = (int)Session["RowCount"];
    int columns = (int)Session["ColumnCount"];
    CreateTable(rows, columns);
  }
}

protected void create_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int rows;
  int columns;
  if (int.TryParse(row.Text, out rows) && int.TryParse(cell.Text, out columns))
  {
    Session["RowCount"] = rows;
    Session["ColumnCount"] = columns;
    CreateTable(rows, columns);
  }
}

private void CreateTable(int aRowCount, int aColumnCount)
{
  pnlTable.Controls.Clear();
  if (aRowCount > 0 && aColumnCount > 0)
  {
    HtmlTable table = new HtmlTable();
    // код заполнения таблицы ...
    pnlTable.Controls.Add(table);
  }
}
```